Datastructures for finding unifiable terms
I am looking for a datastructure that supports the following operations:

Add a term
Remove a term
Return a pair of unifiable terms if one exists.

Ideally, 3 would be as close as possible to returning a pair at random rather than being biased based on e.g. the order the terms were entered.
I suspect there must be a lot of possible answers to this in the literature, so any references are appreciated, especially anything that reviews the state of the art.
I am looking for the most efficient possible (known) implementation of the above.
Bonus points for supporting variations e.g. some higher-order unification

Maybe a variation on union-find? You'd have to be more specific about the semantics of terms and what equivalence relation they are unifiable under.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
